# Bug or hidden feature in Apache Velocity

Tags: java, templates, velocity

I use Apache Velocity 1.7 for Perl code generation. And there is typical Perl syntax for accessing value from hash by key (`$map{key}`) which makes Velocity mad. Here is the code showing my problem:

```
    String template = "#$language hash usage example:\n" +
            "my $value = $map{key};";
    Map<String, Object> context = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    context.put("language", "Perl");
    VelocityContext cntx = new VelocityContext(context);
    StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
    Velocity.evaluate(cntx, output, "Template1", template);
    System.out.println(output.toString());
```

Here is what I have in output:

```
    #Perl hash usage example:
    my $value = $map{;
```

I tried to find something about such behavior in documentation but failed. Does anybody have any ideas what is going on there?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/generic/EscapeTool.html)?

Comment: You see, perl template file could be huge and if I understand you right I have to substitute all dollars there by `${esc.d}`, right? It would be very difficult to maintain this template after such operation. Or you meant something else? I would prefer to understand the problem first though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely a bug. I fixed it in the code base, but while waiting for the next release (which may take a certain time), the following template would keep the perl template file maintainable and avoid the bug:

```
 my $value = $map{ key };
```

Only the preceding space is necessary, the second one is here for aesthetic purpose.